# Adding Custom Attributes to Devise User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise with my Rails 4.2 application and I have custom users controller than I use to navigate to a profile page in the users#show route.  The problem is, if I call

```
@user.username
```

It returns nothing and the value is nil.

Routes:

```
devise_for :users 
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

I also made the following adjustments on the config file via the application_controller:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,:username) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username) }
end
```

The weird thing is, I've seeded the db with default users and they have access to the method.  So that leaves me to believe there's a problem with the form.  But sure enough, I've enabled the field so it's not like I'm not passing in values.

devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %>
</div>
```

Finally, I pass along the user object via the controller like this:

```
def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts.last(5)
end
```

One last thing, if I inspect the user object, it shows that there's a username method but the value is nil.

I've looked at the examples from Devise but still am not getting what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution actually. The method needs to be called with a before action like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
   end 
end
```

It's in the docs here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe add attr_accessor in your user model?

This may override your values to be nil.

Comment: No, I don't set that in the model. It's very weird why the seeded users have the attribute but not if I create it.